# change CSS property on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the javascript code to change the 'left' property of the bat1 div upon key press?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bat1">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#bat1{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler for keypress like this

```
function keyfunction(){
  document.getElementById("bat1").style.left = "300px";
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", keyfunction, false);
```

```js
function keyfunction(){
  document.getElementById("bat1").style.left = "300px";
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", keyfunction, false);
```

```css
#bat1{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bat1">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just done the conditional add color when entter key is press on the button.

```js
$("button").keydown(function(e) {
    //when the key(enter) is pressed  Sets the color ...
    if(e.which === 13) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
$("button").keyup(function() {
    // Removes the color when any key is lifted...
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="anyclass">
I am a button
</button>
```